# help me to find the volume of the ice cream cone!

Tags: integration

Consider the solid shaped like an ice cream cone that is bounded by the functions [image] and [image] Set up an integral in polar coordinates to find the volume of this ice cream cone.

I tried to set up the integral but i have not got any write answer!

Answer (score 1):

$z^2=x^2+y^2$ is a cone, and the other one is a sphere.
Volume to be found is intersection of these. find their intersection, its a circle of radius 4.
Now we will setup the integral in cylindrical coordinates, which are also called half polar coordinates.

$$\int\limits_{0}^{2\pi}\int\limits_{0}^{4}\int\limits_{r}^{\sqrt{32-r^2}} r \cdot dz\,dr\,d\theta$$
is the required volume.